# Dependency on actionlib when building .action files

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, genmsg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

- Up to [today's latest wiki page of actionlib](http://wiki.ros.org/action/recall/actionlib?action=recall&rev=198#Catkin) lists `actionlib` as a required dependency with `actionlib_msgs` to build a package that includes `.action` files, along.
- However, in [Catkin's doc (melodic)](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/building_msgs.html) only `actionlib_msgs` is a required dependency.

  > To generate actions, add actionlib_msgs as a dependency

Which one is correct?

---

UPDATE1: Responding to the comment from @Dirk Thomas:

> The referenced wiki page does not only mention building a package with `.action` files but also contains examples how to use the action server / client. Therefore I would highly suggest to revert your change since it will make the page incomplete / incorrect.

I still think the wiki should present only the minimal dependency example first, so showing dependency on `actionlib_msgs` suffices because:

- The portion of wiki I referred to is specifically under "`.action file`" section.
- It's not official AFAIK, but my understanding is the practice in ROS is to separate message/service/action definition files in a designated package (e.g. #q11835). For a  package that contains .action but no code, adding a dependency on `action_msgs` should be enough, according to [your answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/305701/dependency-on-actionlib-when-building-action-files/?answer=305702#post-id-305702).

  - Of course creating a package that contains both .action files and code that depends on actionlib api is not restricted at all, but I'm not sure if the actionlib's wiki page needs to present that info, let alone in ".action file" section.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/305701/dependency-on-actionlib-when-building-.action-files/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2018-10-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Both are right. It depends what you want to do.

If a package has `.action` files it needs a dependency on `actionlib_msgs` since that package provides the CMake API like `add_action_files()`.

If your package wants to use the API of the `actionlib` package to implement an action server or use an action client than it obviously needs a dependency on that package too.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-10-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2018-10-12**:
Thanks for clarification. Then, because the wiki page section I referred to is about building a package that contains `.action` but not necessarily the code, I dropped `actionlib` from there.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-10-12**:
The referenced wiki page does *not* only mention building a package with `.action` files but also contains examples how to use the action server / client. Therefore I would highly suggest to revert your change since it will make the page incomplete / incorrect.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-10-15**:
Reverted in http://wiki.ros.org/action/diff/actionlib?action=diff&rev1=199&rev2=200

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2018-10-21**:\

> Reverted in http://wiki.ros.org/action/diff/actionlib?action=diff&rev1=199&rev2=200

@Dirk Thomas I responded by updating OP.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-10-22**:
The previous edit of the page reduced the dependencies for only building action files but the remaining of the page actually describes how to use action servers and clients.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-10-22**:
So in order to be consistent if you want to only mention the dependencies for the first part then the second part needs to be updated as well that additional dependencies are necessary using the action server and client. Otherwise the information is misleading (as in your previous edit).